# Append Data in Current UL with id of LI

Tags: jquery

i have following structure in html (due to formatting issues in posting questions i am not writing initial tag before ul and li)

```
<ul>
    <li id="list0">xyz
        <ul>
            <li id="list1">abc</li>
            <li id="list2">abc</li>
            <li id="list3">abc</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now suppose i can pass id as list2 only to the function and that functions does some ajax stuff and give response li id="list4">abc

i want to append this newly added child in ul having li with id "list2".
what will be the selector i tried following but failed

```
function selectUl(id){
   $("#list"+id+"").parent().append('li id="list4">abc</li');  //inserts new list in parent ul 
   $("#list"+id+"").append('li id="list4">abc</li'); //inserts new list after current ul
   $('li id="list4">abc</li').insertAfter("#list"+id+""); //inserts new list after current ul
}
```

Now want to insert new list in current ul tell me now to do this provided that i can only pass id of list inside that ul.

Comment: show us a demo at jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit unsure what you want to achieve here.

You get an ajax response and the ajax response has an ID? Or does it have the actual HTML you want to append?

And do you only want to add a new LI after the current LI with id "list3"? Or do you want to add a new "outer" LI to create a new UL list?

UPDATE:

You do not need to use "insertAfter", you just need to append it to the UL. Like this:

```
var list = document.getElementById("list0").getElementsByTagName("UL")[0]; // Chooses the first UL contained in the list0 LI
var newLI = document.createElement("LI");
newLI.id = "list4";
newLI.innerHTML = "abc";
list.appendChild(newLI);
```

So just put the argumented ID where it fits in this code. Hope that helps :-)

Comment: i only want to add a new LI after the current LI with id "list3" but when i try 
$("#list"+id+"").after('<li id="list4">abc</li>'); 
it inserts new li outside of current ul in which selected li exist

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#list2').after('<li>foo</li>');
```

Or as in your scenario:

```
function selectUl(id){
   $("#list"+id+"").after('<li id="list4">abc</li>');
}
```

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WBCUA/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<li id="list2">def</li>').insertAfter($(document).find("ul #list2"));
```

Comment: i only want to add a new LI after the current LI with id "list3" but when i try 
$('<li id="list2">def</li>').insertAfter($(document).find("ul #list2"));
it inserts new li outside of current ul in which selected li exist